# Removing values in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-analysis

I was wondering what the best way might be to remove all rows from a dataframe if the values in a field were = to values in a different df.

I have df_1 and df_2. df_2 contains a field called id that contains only ids that I want to remove from df_1 can I perform this doing something thats similar to a merging of df but instead of merging just remove or drop all rows that match df_2?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you need `df_1 = df_1[~df_1['col'].isin(df_2['col'])]`

Comment: Thanks! 

So that would give me  df_1,  with none of the values that exist in df_2? or is that the other way around? Sorry!  @jezrael

Comment: Not sure if understand, if not exist no rows are removed? Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if solution not working?

Comment: Sorry -

 I meant I want a df where its basically df_1, but without all rows that exist in df_2 or without all rows that have values in the id col in df_2  @jezrael